# How do I call a PHP function and pass each item of an array as a different parameter?

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function and pass an infinite amount of parameters from an array. This is for use in an HMVC framework to call the controller and pass X amount of parameters so I also welcome any better approaches to this as well.

I'm calling my function like this where $params is an array of a potentially infinite amount of values:

```
controller::$action($params);
```

Then the params would be fully configurable by the programmer in the controller. This would be my example for the edit action:

```
public static function edit($id = false, $group = 'default', etc.){
   // Something
}
```

Comment: [`call_user_func_array`](http://PHP.net/call_user_func_array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function edit ($args) {
   foreach ($args as $arg) {
      echo "Arg = ".$arg;
   }
}

$params = array($id, $group, etc...);
call_user_func_array("edit", array($params));
```